# Jquery find id or form outside parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can you find an id or form outside the parent id?

For example:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a></a>
    </li>
</ul>
<div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <form></form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I get the form information with jQuery when I click on the a href?
Or is this only possible when I give the form an class or id with it?

Comment: Do you want to submit this form?

Comment: What do you mean? As long as the form is inside or outside the parent or children, jQuery is able to get anything in the document..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get `form` reference on click of `a` like following.

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this).closest('ul').next('div').find('form');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery `.closest` [method](https://api.jquery.com/closest/).

here is an example :

```
$('.btn').click(function(){

  var formParent = $(this).closest('form');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to have a wrapper for the entire snippet,

```
<div id="wrapper">
<ul>
    <li>
        <a class="link"></a>
    </li>
</ul>
<div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <form></form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Then, Use

```
$("a.link").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
var form = $(this).parents('#wrapper').find('form'); // the required form
})
```

Comment: This will reduce your DOM traversal steps.

Answer (score 0):

```
var form = $(this).closest('ul').siblings('div').find('form');
```

[.siblings()](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/)

> Description: Get the siblings of each element in the set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.

Note:

Assuming that ul has one sibling div

Answer (score 0):

Traverse it using find.

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <a id="find" style="border:1px solid lawngreen;">Find</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <form>Form Text</form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  $("#find").click(function(){
  
    $("body").find("form").css({"color": "red", "border": "2px solid red"});
});
  
  });
  
</script>
```